# Java JTabbedPane and stateChanged event, getTabCount() with bug?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm not a java developer, but I'm trying to use Netbeans 8.0.1 and java 1.8.0_05 for a wizard application.
I added a JTabbedPane (with 5 tabs) in my project and associated a stateChanged event to enable or disable two button: "next" and "prev".

```
private void tabbedPaneStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt)                                        
{                                            
    bttPrev.setEnabled(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex() > 0);
    bttNext.setEnabled(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex() < (tabbedPane.getTabCount() - 1));
}
```

When I run the application both button are disabled. In debug I have noticed:

```
tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex() = 0
tabbedPane.getTabCount() = 1       ==> should be 5!!!!
```

of course, 0 = 1 - 1 then bttNext was disabled. But why tabbedPane.getTabCount = 1 when it should be 5? If I change tab, it works fine returning 5.
I didn't understand if that is a native bug from java 1.8. Is that possibile, or is there a better and logical explanation that I didn't catch?

[image]

Comment: are u sure?plz check again by putting System.out.println(getTabCount());

Comment: Yes, I am. Please, take a look to the printscreen I just added.
The first row is printed when I'd ran the application. The next ones, when the tab to changed using button next and prev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think the problem is netbeans add statechange to the tabbedpane before add the panels .may be this cause that issue .

and if you put sout after `initcomponent()` method ,

```
//initComponents();
System.out.println("init");
```

.you will see out put as ,

```
1
init
```

so it's clear state event is get fired while executing init component method ,may be when tabs add to pane

what you can do .

add statechange event after add 3 panels not before ..

```
tabbedPane.addTab("lastpanel", jPanel5);

// add statechange event after adding 3 panels
tabbedPane.addChangeListener(new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener() {
        public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
            tabbedPaneStateChanged(evt);
        }
});
```

another simple solution //working well

change state twise at the constructor

add this 2 lines to consructor of your class

```
initComponents();//add following lines after this line
tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(1);
tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(0);
```

Comment: You're right!!! The problem is Netbeans and it's auto-generated code: it adds tabs after statechange event declaration and init.
I've implemented the second solution and it works.
Thank you!